Block one specific device from automatically trying to connect via Bluetooth
I have an Asus laptop running Windows 11 (up-to-date with all updates as of now); my wife has a Fitbit Inspire II health tracker, and every time I switch on the laptop I get an absolute avalanche of requests to pair with the Fitbit - I can cancel the request but it is just repeated every few seconds for quite some time.
Is there a way in Windows 11 to configure Bluetooth to allow/display pairing requests in general but block them specifically for that one device? A simple configuration method would be great but I'm happy to edit the registry if that's what it takes.
All I have been able to find by searching online is how to turn pairing requests off altogether but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it as I change Bluetooth devices from time to time and right now it's only the Fitbit that's causing the pain.

Aren't you fixing this on the wrong end? It's the fitbit that's misbehaving.

@JanDoggen - possibly; however I don't want to stop the Fitbit trying to pair with whatever phone(s) or other devices my wife wants to pair it with, I just want to stop the torrent of requests to pair with my laptop. It's fine that the Fitbit is in promiscuous mode (it's what I'd expect) but I would like my laptop to ignore or block it.

Apparently, there is no Bluetooth "blacklist" for Windows 11. Workarounds: Ask your wife to leave the house. Wrap the FitBit in aluminum foil if it's not in use. [Do not wrap your wife.]

@DrMoishePippik - that's a shame but not a surprise. I think if I suggest foil-wrapping the Fitbit there would be words exchanged (if I suggested foil-wrapping my wife there could be open warfare) so I guess I'll just have to live with it. If you want to write up "no block-list in Windows 11" as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

As far as I can determine, there is no way in Windows OS to blacklist a specific Bluetooth device from connecting.
There was a petition, "Fitbit: Implement Capability to Turn Off Bluetooth Emissions from Your Fitness Trackers," but it apparently has not moved forward. Since there seems to be no way to shut Bluetooth in a FitBit, then one has limited choices.

Keep the FitBit far from the PC. Since Bluetooth claims a range of as much as one kilometer, that may be difficult.
When the watch is not in use, put it in a Faraday cage, which can be as simple as a metal jewelry box, a zippered metallized plastic bag (such as used for some food products), or wrapping in aluminum foil.
Use a keyboard shortcut on the PC to make control of Bluetooth easier. Right-click the Desktop, select New > Shortcut, and set ms-settings:bluetooth for location.


Thank you for writing this up as an answer. I'm still a bit surprised Windows 11 doesn't allow this but I'm sure far wiser heads than mine have considered this and have their reasons.

@Spratty, yes -- Windows has firewall rules and hosts file to limit internet connectivity, why not for Bluetooth?
